# How to make an invisible scrollbar in CScrollView class in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc

I'd like to hide a scrollbar of `CScrollView`-derived view in MFC application.
But, I couldn't find the way to do that.
I know how to diminish the size of the scrollbar to the minimum size, so I can make it invisible in that way, but I literally want to make it invisible not making it minimum size. I have to use the scrollbar while it's invisible. So, please do not suggest setting the size of scrollbar to min value.

Is there any way to make scrollbar literally invisible in `CScrollView`-derived class?

Answer (score 1):

There is `CWnd::ShowScrollBar()` method to do that. So you can simply call:

```
ShowScrollBar( SB_BOTH, FALSE ); // To hide scrollbars
ShowScrollBar( SB_BOTH ); // To show scrollbars
```

Comment: It's not working. I use CStrollView class with SetScrollSizes() and OnHScroll() function. With these functions, what should I do?

Comment: It should and does work as `CScrollView` is derived from `CView` which is derived from `CWnd`.